# Besides the matting, what materials are best for an ESD workbench/table?

Tags: esd, workbench

I need to build my own workbench. I have the matting, the 1 MΩ grounding wire is connected directly to a ground running from an electrical cabinet to the ground.

My table is constructed of Textube and Delrin shelves. It sits directly on the floor with no casters. I can't get close to 1.0 × 10<sup>9</sup> Ω.

I believe it's my table's materials. What do you suggest as a good material for the table for a do-it-yourself?

Comment: What resistance are you referring to?  Between what and what?

Comment: ESD Mats can be used on any table. If you want more durability, you want the table surface itself to be conductive. You don't need both.

Answer (score 2):

An ESD table top usually has a plastic laminate that is built specifically (and marketed for) ESD use. Tabletops can be purchesed (without the legs) with an ESD laminate.

Another option is to purchase a [roll of ESD material](https://www.staticsolutions.com/product/clean-room-mat/) and cut it to the size of the table and then connect it to ground.